How can I connect to my api server on the same IP address from a nextjs application
=== Edited ===
I am building a next js app using an express backend.  Right now I am hosint the frontend (client) and the backend (server) on hostinger.   Using ubuntu and nginx.  When I start the server the frontend works, but I cannot connect to the backend. I am currently just using the ip address I got when setting up the server on hostinger.com.
I also have a copy of the server hosted on AWS in an ec2 instance.  If I pass the ip address of th aws ec2 instance into the NEXT_PUBLIC_API_BASE_URL variable in the .env on the nextjs frontend, it works, but I want to be able to connect to the server hosted on hostinger rather than having the fontend in one pace and the backend somewhere else.
I'm building a nextjs app using an express backend/server.  Have the app setup on a vps with ubuntu.  The app loads but I cannot figure out how to connect to the backend server.
When I try to connect using the ip address of the localhost I get a connect timeout or connecting refused.  I have tried putting the ip address in the NEXT_PUBLIC_API_BASE_URL variable, and I've tried localhost:8000 but nothing works.
Here is my sites-available/default.conf:
server {
     listen 80;
     server_name my_ip_address;
     location / {
          proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
          proxy_http_version 1.1;
          proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
          proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
          proxy_set_header Host $host;
          proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
     }
}

Here is the server/server.js file:
import express from "express";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import cookieParser from "cookie-parser";
import cors from "cors";
import connectDB from "./config/db.js";
import path from "path";
// ROUTES
import userRoutes from "./routes/userRoutes.js";
import dotenv from "dotenv";

dotenv.config();

const port = process.env.PORT || 8000;

connectDB();

const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());

app.use(cors());

// USE ROUTES
app.use("/api/users", userRoutes);

const __dirname = path.resolve();
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "/client/public")));

app.get("*", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "/client/public/index.html"));
});

app.listen(port, "0.0.0.0", () => {
  console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`);
});



Unfortunately, I don't understand much from your description. What is the structure of your application? Do I understand correctly that you use Next.js for the frontend and Express for the backend (API)? What is running on TCP port 3000? Is it Express? What is running on TCP port 8000? Is it Next.js? You are calling frontend as "client" and backend as "server", right? Is your frontend app of SSR (server side rendering) type?

I’ll edit the question in the morning to make it more clear.

Ok, I edited the question.  I hope it makes more sense.
